# canvas constructor getElementById

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

why this doesn't work? i need a solution without appending canvas within 'Can' function.

```
function Can(canvasId) {
this.canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
this.context = this.canvas.getContext('2d');

this.canvas.width = 200;
this.canvas.height = 200;

this.canvas.id = canvasId;

}

var canvas1 = new Can(document.getElementById('can1');
var canvas2 = new Can(document.getElementById('can2');
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/njf2bjmq/3/)

EDIT

i need to wrap both canvases into container and apply constructor function. hope it's more clear now. thanks. [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/njf2bjmq/3/)

Comment: Why are you passing an element into the class?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: What is the issue? `this.canvas.id` is assigned an *element* is this what you want?

Comment: 1.: You have a typo (?): you never close the `new Can(...)`. 2: Why are you even passing `document.getElementById`? `canvasId` is an HTML element, not an actual ID, and even if it was you would a duplicate ID which is invalid.

Comment: i edited my question i hope it make smote sense now. thanks

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Your edited fiddle will successfully create two objects that hold a canvas element and a context for that canvas element.  It's bad form to have the same id for 2 separate html elements (can1 twice and can2 twice).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, it looks like you don't even need to use `createElement()`, because you already have the canvas elements in your html. See if this works for you:

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fm260yp8/1/)**

```
function Can(canvasId) {
    this.canvas = document.getElementById(canvasId);
    this.context = this.canvas.getContext('2d');

    this.canvas.width = 200;
    this.canvas.height = 200;

    this.canvas.id = canvasId;
}

var canvas1 = new Can('can1');
var canvas2 = new Can('can2');
```

This just grabs the reference to the canvas element in the constructor with `getElementById()`.

Answer (score -1):

forgive me if this is ignorant, but at a glance, should 'Can' not be defined as a class?

Comment: i realize that, but you're still applying 'new' to a function.